# nested has_one in active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, activeadmin

I'm using Rails 3.0.10 and ActiveAdmin 0.3.2.

I have a problem with nested form and an has_one association. Using an has_many I can get nested forms but I really need to understand and use an has_one in this case.

Model:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :section
  has_one :seo
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :seo
end

class Seo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
end
```

How write app/admin/article.rb ?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 5):

I'm having exactly the same problem, and here's what I've got working so far:

```
f.inputs "Metadata" do
  f.inputs :for => [:seo_text, f.object.seo_text || SeoText.new] do |meta_form|
    meta_form.input :keywords
    meta_form.input :description
  end
end
```

Unfortunately the styling isn't very nice with out-of-the-box ActiveAdmin 0.6.0, so I'm still looking for a better solution. The [`has_many` helper](http://rubydoc.info/github/gregbell/active_admin/ActiveAdmin/FormBuilder#has_many-instance_method) in ActiveAdmin's form build is close - I basically want a `has_one` version.