# Formtastic form throws "undefined method" error with has_one association

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, formtastic, activeadmin

I am using Rails 3.1 and Ruby 1.9.2 along with Active Admin to build a CMS. Here are my Place and Image models:

```
class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :image    
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :image
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :place 
end
```

Here is the Formtastic form I am rendering in my "new" action in my Places controller:

```
<%= semantic_form_for [:admin, @place] do |p| %>
  <%= p.inputs "Details" do %>
    <%= p.input :name %>
    <%= p.input :description %>
    <%= p.input :phone %>
    <%= p.input :address %>
    <%= p.input :image %>
  <% end %>
  <%= p.buttons %>
<% end %>
```

When I load the form in my browser, I see the following error:

```
undefined method `place_id' for #<Place:0xb801744>
```

Here's the kicker: in my Place model, if I change `has_one :image` to `has_many :images` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for :image` to `accepts_nested_attributes_for :images`, and in my form I change `p.input :image` to `p.input :images`, then the error disappears and Formtastic properly renders a multiselect input element containing all available image objects. So why am I getting this error when I use a `has_one` association rather than seeing a select input element?

Comment: Does Place have an image_id or does Image have place_id. If the latter is working I am guessing that Image has a place_id, if so try putting image_id on Place.

Comment: Since a Place `has_one :image`, the Images table has a foreign key to the Places table.

Comment: true - but since the application of the convention appears wrong i.e. why is it looking for place_id in Place, I thought it might be worth a try.

Comment: seems a related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7833554/nested-has-one-in-active-admin (also unanswered as of this date)

Answer (score 2):

According to https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/575 this is a bug between formtastic and active admin - I suggest you follow the issue on github and also explain your scenario to them, it might prompt a fix, if more than one community member reports the issue.